# Spring context not loading in jboss modules

Tags: module, jboss

We are facing an issue loading a Spring context with modules. Our project structure has a main war (`a.war`) with all the dependencies bundled in `WEB-INF/lib`. We have a separate jar (`b.jar`) which has Camel and CXF integrations and one Spring context XML.  `b.jar` is dependent on another jar inside `a.war`  and `a.war` loads all the Spring context files. While loading we want to load the spring context file from `b.jar` as well.

We tried adding `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with `b.jar` as a dependency but it ends up with expecting the classes from `a.war`.  If we remove this then the application is starting but the Spring context inside `b.jar` is not loaded and getting a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.